# Auto Shutdown / Suspend Vagrant upon shutdown on Windows Host

Tags: windows-7, vagrant

I use vagrant in my development workflow on a Windows machine. Sometimes, I forget to do a `vagrant halt` or `suspend` before restarting or shutting windows down. I read that this could possibly break your VMs.

Is there any way to suspend or shutdown my vagrant VMs automatically when the Win 7 host shuts down?

Comment: For everyone trying, `"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" setextradata "VM NAME" GUI/DefaultCloseAction Shutdown` won't do it for the VirtualBox provider.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this little script : http://blog.ionelmc.ro/2014/01/04/virtualbox-vm-auto-shutdown/ (https://gist.github.com/ionelmc/8245494)

It requires Python on windows, but it's fairly easy to install.